# How do I create an Azure Cognitive Search index for embedded document with $oid unique identifier type?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

My current data structure is something like this,

```
"customer": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "623a4b1bdb6d0a1210fd0234"
        },
        "customerName": "Andrew Jr"
    },
```

I will need to create ACS (Azure Cognitive Search for the above data structure. So I was using something like this:

```
{
        "name": "customer",
        "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
        "fields": 
        [
            {
            "name": "customerName",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true, 
            "filterable": true, 
            "sortable": true, 
            "facetable": true
            }
        ]
     },
```

But it will throw errors to me when I add the _id as a string data type, for example, below:

```
{
        "name": "customer",
        "type": "Edm.ComplexType", 
        "fields": 
        [
            {
                "name": "_id",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "searchable": true, 
                "filterable": true, 
                "sortable": true, 
                "facetable": true
                },
            {
            "name": "customerName",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true, 
            "filterable": true, 
            "sortable": true, 
            "facetable": true
            }
        ]
     },
```

Any ideas how to add the following format to the search?

```
 "_id": {
        "$oid": "623a4b1bdb6d0a1210fd0234"
    },
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting the error is because of invalid name for the field (`_id`).

Based on the naming rules defined [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/naming-rules#chart-of-naming-rules), a field name can only contain letters, numbers, underscores ("_") however the first character of the field name must be a letter.

Since you are naming your field as `_id`, you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the issue. The front end Java developer said he could only use _id for the Java front end update to work so he has to give the column name for the mongodb collection to be _id. How can I reference _id for the ACS search column? I tried doc_id as what is being used for the _id for the document but not working.

Comment: It is not clear from your question as to how the data is being sent from frontend to the cognitive search. I would be guessing but you can apply some JSON transformation so that your `_id` field maps to `doc_id` field when saving the data and opposite when retrieving the data. HTH.

Comment: I have mongodb as the backend database and we are using java to feed the mongodb data from the front end. The data structure were from the java script insert:
"customer": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "623a4b1bdb6d0a1210fd0234"
        },
        "customerName": "Andrew Jr"
    }, so I will need to create ACS to search for this dataset so _id is one of the column and now giving me trouble for creating index.

Comment: You can create a datasource for your mongoldb database. It's in preview right now (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/preview-api/create-or-update-data-source). Then you can create an indexer with appropriate mapping (`_id` attribute mapping to `doc_id`) and let Cognitive Search handle this transformation for you.

Comment: How can I "apply some JSON transformation so that your _id field maps to doc_id" ?

Comment: Please see my last comment. That I believe would be the best way for you to proceed IMHO.

Comment: This is what I defined from the indexer:

"fieldMappings": [ { "sourceFieldName" : "_id", "targetFieldName" : "id" } ],
On the index definition I have used the id instead of _id:
When I was trying to save the indexer, I got the following error:
Field mapping specifies target field 'id' that doesn't exist in the index

I wonder whether the mapping should be reference to customer embedded document column _id. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please post a new question and provide details about the indexer and index definition there.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71593712/azure-cognitive-search-how-to-map-embedded-document-column