# Azure Cognitive Search: How to map embedded document column?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have mongodb as the backend datasource when creating the ACS index and some columns from mongodb is _id. Per definition of the ACS indexer the name can not start with _ so I will need to create some mapping for the mongodb collection columns to the ACS index names.

The mongodb data is like below:

```json
"customer": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "623a4b1bdb6d0a1210fd0234"
        },
        "customerName": "Andrew Jr"
    }
```

The ACS index definition I created is:

```json
{
            "name": "customer",
            "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "filterable": true,
                    "retrievable": true,
                    "sortable": true,
                    "facetable": true,
                    "key": false,
                    "indexAnalyzer": null,
                    "searchAnalyzer": null,
                    "analyzer": null,
                    "normalizer": null,
                    "synonymMaps": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "customerName",
                    "type": "Edm.String",
                    "searchable": true,
                    "filterable": true,
                    "retrievable": true,
                    "sortable": true,
                    "facetable": true,
                    "key": false,
                    "indexAnalyzer": null,
                    "searchAnalyzer": null,
                    "analyzer": null,
                    "normalizer": null,
                    "synonymMaps": []
                }
            ]
        }
```

So basically I want to map the field _id inside customer embedded document from the mongodb data source to the index column id.

I tried to use the indexer to map them together :

```
 "fieldMappings": [ { "sourceFieldName" : "_id", "targetFieldName" : "id" } ],
```

I am getting the error: Field mapping specifies target field 'id' that doesn't exist in the index

How can I define the sourceFieldName and targertFieldName to reference to embedded document ?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been struggling with this too - if your issue is the same as mine, I don't think it is possible unfortunately.

In the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings?tabs=rest), near the top of the page it says field mappings apply to:

> Top-level search fields only, where the "targetFieldName" is either a simple field or a collection. A target field can't be a complex type.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "targetFieldName" value to "name" instead of "id" and check with the execution.

```
"fieldMappings": [ { "sourceFieldName" : "_id", "targetFieldName" : "id" } ],
```

Comment: I got the error message: Field mapping specifies target field 'name' that doesn't exist in the index

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the field mappings of an existing indexer using the [Update Indexer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-indexer) request.

```
PUT https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/myindexer?api-version=[api-version]
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: [admin key]
{
    "dataSourceName" : "mydatasource",
    "targetIndexName" : "myindex",
    "fieldMappings" : [ { "sourceFieldName" : "_id", "targetFieldName" : "id" } ]
```

A source field can be referenced in multiple field mappings.

```
"fieldMappings" : [
    { "sourceFieldName" : "text", "targetFieldName" : "textStandardEnglishAnalyzer" },
    { "sourceFieldName" : "text", "targetFieldName" : "textSoundexAnalyzer" }
]
}
```

Comment: My issue here is that it doesn't recognize the column name _id inside the embedded document. Please see my ACS definition above.